# Can't preview Phonegap console.logs on ecilpse

Tags: cordova, adt

I can't see my console.logs on eclipse console

- adt 22.3.0
- android 4.1
- galaxy note 10.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logcat is the thing that you should use for such debugging options.

In Eclipse, Goto Window-> Show View -> Other -> Android-> Logcat.

Logcat is nothing but a console of your Emulator or Device where you can get all the dumps out.

Comment: I did that and didn't worked apparently sometimes you just have to restart the eclipse